# With or without whom/who

Tags: american-english, british-english

**A person whom/ who i admire**

**A person i admire.**

What is the difference between these 2 setences with regards to the  usage of whom/who?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Who* and *whom* aren't supposed to be interchangeable - "who" is a *subjective* pronoun, while "whom" is an *objective* pronoun. In other words, if it refers to the *subject* of the sentence, use "who"; if it's the *object* of the verb or a preposition, then use "whom".

In your example "I" is the subject, and the person is an object of the verb "admire", so it should be "*a person **whom** I admire*".

Your second example which omits the pronoun entirely is fine - but only because it should be "whom". Because 'the person' is the object of the verb, the sentence is complete without it - just as you could say "I admire this person".

Having said all that, "whom" is considered to be *formal* by some, and many native English speakers don't use it in everyday conversation - they would either omit it, as per your second example, or use "who".